# Postgresql jsonb_agg subquery sort

Tags: json, postgresql, subquery

*How can I sort the results of a subquery that's using a json aggregate?*

If I had a schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE plans( id integer NOT NULL, name character varying(255));
CREATE TABLE plan_items ( id integer NOT NULL, plan_id integer NOT NULL, expected_at date, status integer);
```

I'm aggregating the plan_items result on a json column through a subquery.
Like this:

```
SELECT
  plans.id,
  plans.name,
  jsonb_agg((SELECT pi_cols FROM 
       (SELECT plan_items.id, plan_items.expected_at, plan_items.status) pi_cols
      )) AS plan_items_data
FROM
  plans
  INNER JOIN plan_items ON plan_items.plan_id = plans.id
GROUP BY
  plans.id,
  plans.name
ORDER BY plans.id;
```

The JSON aggregate is working as expected and give me the results that I need. Ok.
But I can't order the results.

I've tried:

```
  jsonb_agg((SELECT pi_cols FROM 
       (SELECT plan_items.id, plan_items.expected_at, plan_items.status ORDER BY plan_items.expected_at) pi_cols
      )) AS plan_items_data
```

and also:

```
  jsonb_agg((SELECT pi_cols FROM 
       (SELECT plan_items.id, plan_items.expected_at, plan_items.status) pi_cols ORDER BY pi_cols.expected_at
      )) AS plan_items_data
```

But none of these solved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use the extended form of aggregate: `jsonb_agg(... order by plan_items.expected_at)`

Answer (score 22):

As [Abelisto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593144/abelisto) suggests, just use a simple [aggregate expression with ordering](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
jsonb_agg(plan_items ORDER BY plan_items.expected_at) AS plan_items_data
```

Answer (score 3):

Join the tables with the desirable sort order and use lateral join to select columns for `jsonb_agg()`:

```
select s.plan_id id, name, jsonb_agg(pi_col)
from (
    select p.id plan_id, p.name, pi.id, expected_at, status
    from plans p
    join plan_items pi 
    on p.id = pi.plan_id
    order by p.id, expected_at
    ) s,
lateral (
    select plan_id id, expected_at, status
    ) pi_col
group by 1, 2
order by 1;
```

The above query seems to be more natural and flexible (and a bit faster in most cases) than the one with a subquery in a select list. However for better performance you should also apply Abelisto's suggestion:

```
select s.plan_id id, name, json_agg(pi_col order by pi_col.expected_at)
from (
    select p.id plan_id, p.name, pi.id, expected_at, status
    from plans p
    join plan_items pi 
    on p.id = pi.plan_id
    ) s,
lateral (
    select plan_id id, expected_at, status
    ) pi_col
group by 1, 2
order by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks klin, but I don't think that a lateral is needed on this query... It looks like Abelisto's comment was enough. 

Comment: The lateral join is not a special feature here, it's just the way I would prefer to write queries like this one. Of course, an aggregate with `order by` clause is a good solution.